# how to inject a variable in a OneToOne relation entity

Tags: file, symfony, path, upload, directory

I have a File entity for handle files upload in other entities (news/blog/etc).

I point to it with a OneToOne relation and it works fine. But I would change the upload dir, for each relation entity :

upload/news
upload/blog

The upload path is set in my file entity so i dont know how to automaticaly update the path foreach relations...
do you have an idea on how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: please show your file entity definition

Comment: it will not help you..  ^^ @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File", cascade={"persist"})

Comment: you cannot associate an attribute with a OneToOne Association, so either you store your path with your file entity (which is the targetEntity and you didn't show it) or you resolve your association to a OneToMany/ManyToOne where you can have attributes on your association like e.g. your path - but I don't see any sense in this.

Comment: Yes, I know that, the thing I want to know is how to do it anyway :)

Comment: So the answer is - you can't. Only thing I can think of is to save the path as an extra attribute with your file entity - but you're not willing to show it obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do it.
On your file entity side, you can add a uploadDir attribute, and create a setter like this :

```
private $uploadDir;

public function setUploadDir($uploadDir)
{
    if (!$this->uploadDir) {
        $this->uploadDir = $uploadDir;
    }
}
```

your comment suggest you use Symfony with Doctrine right ?

So you can edit the classical getUploadDir() method like this:

```
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/' . $this->uploadDir;
}
```

In the 'parent' entity you have to update this attribute (when it is created) before persist or update.

(I personally use life cycle callbacks but you can do it manually in your controller)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * News
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="News")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class News
{ 
    //....

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File",cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
function setUploadDir()
{
    $this->getFile()->setUploadDir('news');
}
// ....
```

You can also add a constant to make the code cleaner...
I hope it'll help you